# Why is the Visual Studio exception assistant so slow?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

When there's an exception, it takes a few seconds for the exception assistant to pop up. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably unwinding the stack. If you don't need that, go to Tools->Options->Debugging->General "Unwind the call stack on unhandled exceptions".